# CSS format for checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, each one with a label:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="patient-birth_city" name="patient-birth_city" />
    <label for="patient-birth_city">(_PATIENT_BIRTH_CITY_)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="patient-birth_state" name="patient-birth_state" />
    <label for="patient-birth_state">(_PATIENT_BIRTH_STATE_)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="patient-birth_country" name="patient-birth_country" />
    <label for="patient-birth_country">(_PATIENT_BIRTH_COUNTRY_)</label>
```

[Without using any CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/sLHAJ/) they are showed in the same line (I suppose they have a default "inline" or "block-inline" display). The problem is I can't modify HTML structure and I need each pair checkbox-label appear in a new line. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/VW529/). Is it possible using only CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The good thing about `label` tags is you can wrap the `input` elements:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="birth_city" name="birth_city" />
    City
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="birth_state" name="birth_state" />
    State
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="birth_country" name="birth_country" />
    Country
</label>
```

And if you add the following CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;   
}
```

It will display it how you want.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/VF8ve/)

As you CAN'T edit your HTML, this CSS would work:

```
input, label {
    float: left;   
}

input {
    clear: both;    
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/VF8ve/2/)

Comment: he says he can't modify html structure, so this is not a solution. please read the question.

Answer (score 4):

Using float:left and clear:left you can do this with only css.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VW529/2/

```
input {margin:3px;}
input, label {float:left;}
input {clear:left;}
```

The only problem is that the example does not show more information of parent elements, giving the container element overflow:hidden and/or clear:both might be needed to prevent floating elements next to the last label. (edited jsfiddle code with container div)

Comment: whoever gave this a -1: please explain why!

Comment: +1 Clear and Float might be the only way to go as HMTL structure can't be changed, so I'm no sure either.

Comment: yep, edited my code, overflow:hidden was all that was needed, position:relative had no effect (FF6)